# finding way to know if php page printed -ctrl p - and update in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Hello I have `php` website that is working like a system for accounting..

I have receipt, invoice etc..

I have a problem in `mySQL` database main table I have in Main_table variable how_much_ printed and via `php` and `mySql` I need to update it. Every time that user does even ctrl P

How do I do that?

The reason is that in law I need to print on the first document that its source document.

I didn't find any way so I decided to block the printing with `css` and do printing web page separately - its looks ugly if someone can find way?

Thanks alot for help
Yan

Comment: You do realize that it's completely irrelevant how many times someone prints it? Also you will never know the true count of copies, even if you intercept Ctrl-P. I can just tell the printer to print it 20, but you will just log it as once.

Comment: This is a lost cause, a fight you can't win. You can save a page as HTML and print it later, you can export it as a PDF. There's a million ways to get around this and all you're doing is presenting ridiculous obstacles to a person who can and will circumvent them if they want to.

Comment: check the rules for `Computer-generated document` in your place. I don't think there needs to be a difference between first copy and others (duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to block Ctrl + P then call ajax to php server and update how_much_ printed field, after update, print document on success callback of ajax

```
jQuery(document).bind("keyup keydown", function(e){
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80){
     e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "some.php",
        data: { },
        success: function(data){
          window.print();
        }
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: This whole exercise is futile. This doesn't trap the menu item equivalent.